# Assigning numbers to pointers to char

Tags: c, udp, u-boot

I'm writing a modification to udp protocol in u-boot's netconsole (the board is xilinx's zedboard).

I need to have the packets numbered. I've located the function responsible for sending and I wanted to start by simply adding a number at the beginning of each packet. It works just fine, as long as I pass the value in double quotes - "@".

When I want to just pass a number (or even if I use a single character - '@' instead of "@") I get completely random value when I receive the packet.

```
static void nc_send_packet(const char *buf, int len)
{
    struct eth_device *eth;
    int inited = 0;
    uchar *pkt;
    uchar *ether;
    IPaddr_t ip;

    uchar *new_buf=malloc((len+1)*(sizeof(uchar))); //TN
    uchar *prefix="@"; //<-------------------------------this line TN
    memcpy(new_buf, prefix, 1); //TN
    memcpy((new_buf+1), buf, len);    //TN
    len+=1; //TN

    debug_cond(DEBUG_DEV_PKT, "output: \"%*.*s\"\n", len, len, buf);

    eth = eth_get_dev();

    if (eth == NULL)
        return;

    if (!memcmp(nc_ether, NetEtherNullAddr, 6)) {
        if (eth->state == ETH_STATE_ACTIVE)
            return; /* inside net loop */

        output_packet = new_buf;  //TN was output_packet = buf;
        output_packet_len = len;

        NetLoop(NETCONS); /* wait for arp reply and send packet */

        output_packet_len = 0;
        free(new_buf); //TN

        return;
    }

    if (eth->state != ETH_STATE_ACTIVE) {
        if (eth_is_on_demand_init()) {
            if (eth_init(gd->bd) < 0)
                free(new_buf);  //TN
            return;
            eth_set_last_protocol(NETCONS);
        } else
            eth_init_state_only(gd->bd);

        inited = 1;
    }
    pkt = (uchar *)NetTxPacket + NetEthHdrSize() + IP_UDP_HDR_SIZE;
    memcpy(pkt, new_buf, len);  //TN was memcpy(pkt, buf, len); 
    ether = nc_ether;
    ip = nc_ip;
    NetSendUDPPacket(ether, ip, nc_out_port, nc_in_port, len);

    free(new_buf);//TN

    if (inited) {
        if (eth_is_on_demand_init())
            eth_halt();
        else
            eth_halt_state_only();
    }
}
```

The lines with //TN have been added by me. I need to have something like this:

`uchar * prefix = 0x40;` or `uchar * prefix = 64;` What is even stranger (for me at least) is that
 `uchar * prefix = '@';` also doesn't work. I have tried casting it, but neither `uchar * prefix = (uchar)0x40;` nor `uchar * prefix = (uchar)'@';` work.

I was also wondering, if it were possible to have a longer field for that, so that I have for example 2 bytes for the packet number instead of just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is your data type.

Your variable `uchar * prefix` is type pointer-to-char.

The literal `"@"` is a string, which is represented as a pointer-to-char.

The literal `'@'` is a character.

When you say `uchar * prefix = "@"`, you're assigning a pointer to a pointer and everything happens as expected.  When you say `uchar * prefix = '@'`, you are implicitly converting the numeric value of that ASCII character (0x40) into a pointer.  When you de-reference that pointer you'll get whatever happens to be at memory address 0x40, which is probably not what you're trying to do.  If you're compiling with all of your warnings turned on, your compiler should have flagged the implicit conversion.

You have two possible solutions.  Either use the string literal instead of the character, or change `prefix` to be type `char` instead.